# In what directory should I install Jetty on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, java, file-location

I've downloaded jetty-6.1.14.zip into my home directory on my Ubuntu 8.04 box. Where is the appropriate place to unzip it?

I put it in /opt because /opt is supposedly for "storing random data that has no other logical destination", and I could think of no other logical destination.

I was thinking that /usr/local might be the right place, but it didn't seem like it was unquestionably the right place. I read somewhere that /usr/local is for "user-installed applications" but a webserver doesn't really seem like an "application" to me. Maybe that's just poor wording by the author? (Or poor understanding of what "application" means by me?)

If anyone knows what the appropriate/idiomatic/"linux-y" place to put Jetty is, and you can explain why that's the case, I think that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

personally, i'm installing in /opt because it is empty and only three letters. in the end it doesn't matter.

and a general hint, create a symlink to the current version. you don't have to update defined paths later (i.e. "ln -s jetty-version-x.y/ current" where current points to the jetty directory and you can update it later with "ln -sf ...")

Answer (score 2):

An 'apt-get install jetty' would install jetty 5.1.14-1 in /usr/share/jetty.
Check out the file list found here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/all/jetty/filelist

This might be useful for orientation while manually installing jetty 6.1.14.

Answer (score 2):

I found this helpful http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debian+Packages